# Group in rows and column

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I am sort of new to sql and I have a question that I havent been able to resolve, I have a view that combines info from different tables doing different operations and basically, simplified, it looks a bit like this:

```
Risk_Status    Task_Name     Completion 
---------------------------------------
Green              Task1        On Time 
Yellow             Task2        Delayed 
Yellow             Task3        On Time 
Green              Task4        Delayed
Red                Task5        Delayed
Yellow             Task5        Delayed
Red                Task5        On Time
Red                Task5        Delayed
```

What I want to accomplish is to group all tasks by status, following the count of tasks that fall on each status AND have a column that list all delayed or on time tasks that fall in the different statuses as well:

```
Status      Number of Tasks    Number of Delayed Tasks
-------------------------------------------------------
Green                     2                          1
Yellow                    3                          2
Red                       3                          2
```

I have tried duplicating the view in the from clause and making it select only delayed tasks on the where class but it's not giving me accurate results, I'm not sure what else to try.

Any help is appreciated :)

Comment: Welcome to SO:SE. Please provide your best attempt are solving this problem, so that users can help fix it. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use conditional aggregation:

```
select status, count(*) as NumTasks,
       sum(case when completion = 'Delayed' then 1 else 0 end) as NumDelayedTasks
from yourview
group by status;
```

Comment: So simple! Thanks so much! Thanks to @PhilWalton too! :)

Answer (score 1):

Hey you can use the below Query.

```
WITH sample_data(riskstatus,taskname,completion)
AS
(
SELECT 'Green','Task1','On Time' FROM dual
UNION ALL
SELECT 'Yellow','Task2','Delayed' FROM dual
UNION ALL
SELECT 'Yellow','Task3','On Time' FROM dual
UNION ALL
SELECT 'Green','Task4','Delayed' FROM dual
UNION ALL
SELECT 'Red','Task5','Delayed' FROM dual
UNION ALL
SELECT 'Yellow','Task5','Delayed' FROM dual
UNION ALL
SELECT 'Red','Task5','On Time' FROM dual
UNION ALL
SELECT 'Red','Task5','Delayed' FROM dual
)
SELECT riskstatus,count(taskname),sum(decode(completion,'Delayed',1,0))
FROM sample_data
GROUP BY riskstatus;
```